# Why earring is twisted for Buck star? [4,4]

Tags: cryptic-clues

British (cryptic) crossword puzzle hint:

Why earring is twisted for Buck star?   [4,4]

Comment: not clear about are you asking a question or telling an answer to previous puzzle ? :( but i haven't down voted...since you might would like to explain :)

Comment: I think it's clear enough to people who know Cryptics. Unfortunately, this is a clue that's vague enough that I'd probably need to cross some letters in order to figure it out, and I don't really have that option here.

Comment: I am asking a question.  There is no previous puzzle (that I know of).

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.....

Comment: We don't understand the question...  could you make it more clear what we're supposed to do?

Comment: It's a cryptic crossword  (as cited)  Look here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Erin Gray

because apparently

> she starred in a Buck Rogers TV series long ago. I'd never heard of it before, but the *Buck star* part gave it away. ([Thanks, Wikipedia!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers_in_the_25th_Century_(TV_series)))
> And her name is an anagram of "Y EARRING", as I'm sure you already realised.

Comment: Ahhhh. I had the anagram part down, but I've never heard of the show...

Comment: Um, check the wikipedia link a bit more closely.

Comment: @Jiminion Haha, yes I see what you mean

Comment: How have none of you heard of Buck Rogers? I wasn't even born yet, but I know about it because Daffy Duck used to be featured in Duck Rogers shorts on Looney Tunes. Come on, guys!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think we've all heard of Buck Rogers. I was referring to the TV show that ran for 2 series about 35 years ago.

Comment: So much for my guess about the coffee store. :-(